# Django: filter on a self-reference foreign key attribute

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

In my Django 2.2 app, I have a model like this:

```py
class Folder(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    parent_folder = models.ForeignKey("Folder", null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Basically, a folder can have a parent, this folder's parent itself can have a parent, and so on.

So what I would like to do is, order the folders on their `name` attributes and starting with the top-level folders (so, the folders with no `parent_folder`) and then descending in the folder hierarchy.

To illustrate, given the following objects in the table:

```
+----+---------+---------------+
| id |  name   | parent_folder |
+----+---------+---------------+
|  1 | fuel    | <None>        |
|  2 | blabla  | 1             |
|  3 | volcano | 2             |
|  4 | awful   | 2             |
|  5 | apple   | 1             |
|  6 | amazing | <None>        |
|  7 | wow     | 6             |
+----+---------+---------------+
```

The ordered output I except is:

```
+----+---------+---------------+
| id |  name   | parent_folder |
+----+---------+---------------+
|  6 | amazing | <None>        |
|  7 | wow     | 6             |
|  1 | fuel    | <None>        |
|  5 | apple   | 1             |
|  2 | blabla  | 1             |
|  4 | awful   | 2             |
|  3 | volcano | 2             |
+----+---------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend using [`django-mptt`](https://django-mptt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/models.html) for this, which can be installed via `pip3 install django-mptt`.

Add `mptt` to `INSTALLED_APPS`, then modify your model:

```
from mptt.models import MPTTModel, TreeForeignKey

class Folder(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
```

Now you can simply call `Folder.get_family()` and your queryset will be sorted in "tree order" by default.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks I didn't know about MPTT. :)

Comment: @Spacebrain That was exactly my reaction when I found out about it

Answer (score 2):

Can be easily achieved by usage of [Django MPTT](https://django-mptt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

What you need, is returned by `.get_family()` (see [docs](https://django-mptt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/models.html#get-family)).